# SSRS Group Footer - Expression to show a certain row from dataset

Tags: reporting-services, expression

This is a report for Reps showing the customers sales for the previous day and the reps budget for the customer.  So in my query I've already calculated the customer total, budget etc. which I managed to put into the report.  The problem I have now is that the report's display is toggled so in the group footer I need to display the customer's total as well.  I can not sum the column then it will include the budget.  I need to input a expression, something like this:

```
=Tons WHERE ItemDesc = "Customer Total"
```

I have tried to google for a solution but all I can find is `IIF` statments.  Is there anyway to do this?

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this...

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ItemDesc.Value = "Customer Total", Fields!Tons.Value, 0))
```

All we are doing here is evaluating each row's ItemDesc, if it's "Customer Total" grab the Tons value if not grab 0... then sum all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alan Schofield but that did not work.  After more searching I went with the lookup:

I added a second dataset with only the totals, then in the expresion for the footer I did the following:

```
= Lookup (Fields!Customer.Value,
Fields!Customer.Value,  
Fields!Tons.Value,
"DataSet2")
```

This example helped me alot:  http://www.sql-datatools.com/2015/07/lookup-functions-in-ssrs.html